# ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence only on certain loops

Tags: python

I'm trying to get my program to read incoming log files from an external program. The program runs a function and then I have it scheduled to repeat every 10 seconds. The program runs fine for a few iterations and then gives me 'ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence', I've tried to pass an error exception but feel my understanding is lacking and as such haven't implemented it properly.

The incoming log files are not a uniform matrix and they may change in size so I'm finding the max length and creating a matrix of zeros to populate the empty results with 0's to allow for manipulation.

```
CheckFile = 0
CurrentFile = 0

def MyFunction():
    from datetime import datetime
    global CheckFile
    global CurrentFile
    month = datetime.now().strftime('%B')
    path = os.path.join(r'C:\MyFilePath',month) #I add month because the files change location each month
    os.chdir(path)

    for i in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,i)) and 'StartOfFileName$}' in i:
            filelist = [i]

    Filehandle = filelist[0]    
    strFile = str(File_3min)
    CurrentFile = strFile[14:44]
    Current = CurrentFile

    if Current != CheckFile:  # This statement checks to make sure that the log files are always new

        with open(Filehandle ,'r') as Filehandle :
            lines = [line.strip().split(',') for line in Filehandle ]

        max_len = max(len(line) for line in lines)
        my_array = np.zeros([len(lines),max_len])

        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            my_array[i, :len(line)] = line

    else:
        return

schedule.every(10).seconds.do(MyFunction)


while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

The error arises from the line: max_len = max(len(line) for line in lines)

Comment: The file you're opening is empty thus you have `lines == []`... don't do the processing if that's the case or whatever fits into how you want to handle it... Or maybe, if you're using 3.4+, you can pass `default=0` into `max` and then the rest of your code will run but will effectively be a no-op. Whatever suites/makes the most sense.

Comment: The files all have data inside of them, i've check through all of them immediately after the error. Thanks i'm using python 3.6 so i'll passing default as 0

Comment: Please have a look at [mcve]. Currently your example isn't minimal and not reproducible and is missing the expected behavior. That makes it very hard to give useful answer to your question.

Comment: @Rodrigo Interesting - the only way you'd get that exception is by passing in an empty iterable to `max` so are you really, really sure you don't have an empty file?

Comment: Im sure been having this issue for 2 days, it doesn't really make much sense. I think I might just have a go at going around it another way